# CommandLine Application with Hibernate + Annotations Only

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

Is it possible to use Hibernate with Annotations, without Spring framework for a command line application.

Right now i have spring with hibernate configured for command line application.I have main function which received data and it calls other (namely 'storeDB') object to get AbstractApplicationContext context and save the data.

1. Like to bring up the hibernate first ( bring up hibernate framework,
   connecting to DB) and like to wait for a socket to process the data.
   Can it be configured through java configuration than XML
   configuration
2. and is it possible do in Hibernate(with annotation) without Spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course you can:

1. Use Hibernate annotations (without XML configuration) to setup your database connections and map
      your entities to your database, for further information about it take a look at:

> - **[Hibernate with Annotation](http://www.javatpoint.com/hibernate-with-annotation)**.
> - **[TutorialsPoint Hibernate - Annotations tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_annotations.htm)**.

2. Use only `Hibernate` without `Spring` in a Java Application to manage your persistence strategies, because they are two independents frameworks:

> You can see from the **[Hibernate Definition](http://hibernate.org/orm/)** that:
>
> *Hibernate ORM enables developers to more easily write applications whose data outlives the application process. As an Object/Relational Mapping (ORM) framework, Hibernate is concerned with data persistence as it applies to relational databases (via JDBC).*
>
> And from the **[Spring project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/)** definition that:
>
> *The Spring Framework provides a comprehensive programming and configuration model for modern Java-based enterprise applications - on any kind of deployment platform. A key element of Spring is infrastructural support at the application level: Spring focuses on the "plumbing" of enterprise applications so that teams can focus on application-level business logic, without unnecessary ties to specific deployment environments.*

**Conclusion:**

As you can see `Hibernate` and `Spring` are two differents frameworks that handles differents levels of Java Applications.

Comment: Autowired annotation is available in hibernate?

Comment: No `autowired` annotation is part of spring framework and doesn't exist in Hibernate.